# How do I get all versions of an S3 key and undelete using boto?

Tags: amazon-s3, versioning, boto, undelete

I have had an S3 bucket for awhile but only now turned versioning on. Experimenting with it a bit trying to figure out what sort of detection protections I am getting with just the versioning on, without activating the "MFA delete" option.

I uploaded a test file, then deleted it then re-uploaded it twice. Now, using [the S3 browser tool](http://the%20S3%20browser%20tool)  I am seeing 4 versions of the file: #1, #2 (deleted), #3 and #4 (current). If I use `boto` to get the latest version, I can extract its `version_id`:

```
import boto
c=boto.connect_s3()
b=c.get_bucket('my-bucket')
k = b.get_key('test2/dw.txt')
print k.version_id
```

But how do i get a full list of version_id's for a given key? And if I want to retrieve version #1 of the key (deleted), do I need to do something first using the version #2 id to "undelete" it?

Finally, does this deletion protection (creation of a delete marker) work with legacy files that had been uploaded before versioning was turned on?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a list of all available versions by using the `list_versions` method of the bucket object.

```
import boto
c = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = c.get_bucket('my-bucket')
for version in bucket.list_versions():
    print(version)
```

This will return a list of `Key` objects which have specific `version_ids` associated with them.  You can retrieve any of the versions but using the normal methods on the `Key` object.  If you want to make the older version the current version you would have to re-upload it or copy it on the server.

Once you enable versioning on a bucket, all delete operations after that point in time on any object in the bucket will result in a delete marker being written to the bucket rather than actually deleting the object.

Comment: So does it mean that the only way to get a list of versions for a key is to get the complete list for the whole bucket using `bucket.list_versions()` and then loop over all the keys the way you show and test for a match of `version.name` and the name of the key I am interested in? That seems like a strange design decision on the part of AWS/boto folks, although maybe there is something that justifies it that I don't understand...

Comment: No, the ``list_versions`` method takes a parameter called ``prefix`` that can be used to limit the results returned.  If the key you are interested in is called foobar, then ``list_versions(prefix="foobar")`` should limit the results to just the versions for that key.

Answer (score 4):

You can get list of all version using following method

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)

s3 = session.client('s3')

bucket_name = 'bucketname'

versions = s3.list_object_versions (Bucket = bucket_name, Prefix = 'Key')

print(versions.get('Versions'))
```

This will print a list of all versions present in that bucket along with other information like key, storage class, size etc

Comment: N.b. that with `boto3`, you must manually handle pagination yourself, which this simple example does not do.

Comment: @Thanatos or use `boto3`'s built-in pagination helpers:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#paginators
Another gotcha that people seem to gloss over is `prefix` is just that: a prefix.  It's not an exact match.  If you have the files `file`, `file2`, and `file3`, then `prefix="file"` will match _all_ of those keys.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see an answers that also undoes the delete marker, so here is a script that I use to specifically undelete one object, you can potentially ignore the ENDPOINT if you use AWS S3.

- This version uses the pagination helpers in case there are more versions of the object than fit in one response (1000 by default).
- I create an s3.ObjectVersion using the returned VersionId and then delete() that to restore the object.

```
import boto3
import sys

ENDPOINT='10.62.64.200'

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: {} bucketname key".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

bucketname = sys.argv[1]
key = sys.argv[2]

s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url='http://' + ENDPOINT)
kwargs = {'Bucket' : bucketname, 'Prefix' : key}

pageresponse = s3.meta.client.get_paginator('list_object_versions').paginate(**kwargs)

for pageobject in pageresponse:
    if 'DeleteMarkers' in pageobject.keys() and pageobject['DeleteMarkers'][0]['Key'] == key:
        print("Undeleting s3://{}/{}".format(bucketname, key))
        s3.ObjectVersion(bucketname, key, pageobject['DeleteMarkers'][0]['VersionId']).delete()
```